# Simple Netlogo programming

Tags: netlogo

In my netlogo program I have a ratio that fluctuates over time.

In the program time is set to weeks. There are 5200 weeks in each simulation.

If the ratio falls below 0.70 I would like to set a parameter R0 to zero for 520 weeks then go back to the baseline of 0.03.

Right now I have

```
ifelse ( ratio < T ) [ set R0 0 ] [set R0 0.03]
```

where T is set to 0.70, however, how do I set R0 to 0 for ten years and then back to 0.03?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

With the code you have RO is always set to 0 or 0.03.

Assuming each tick is a month use a variable called timer

```
if timer > 0 [set timer timer - 1 if timer = 0 [set ratio 0.03]]
if (ratio < T)[set ratio 0 set timer 120]
```

it works as well for a patch, a turtle or a global

Comment: Thank you so much. How does the above code set R0 to zero though?

Comment: when is it supposed to be set to zero?

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I will give it a try. Perhaps you can help with the next step. The next step is to increase R0 every 3 months by 0.25 until it hits 0.06. For example, from timer 0 to 75 ratio is greater than T. At timer 76 ratio is less than T so set R0 to 0 for 120 months. At timer 296 then increase R0 by 0.25 and keep doing that until R0 hits 0.06 and then stop.

Comment: I tried the code exactly as above and received the following error:if expected two inputs, a TRUE/FALSE and a command block.

Comment: I edited the code (added [] for the actions after the if) and that should fix the syntax error. If you have a separate question, then please ask a new question (and accept the answer for this one). But you probably don't need to if you think through how this actually works - you just need to work out what the rules are and the conditions when they apply.

Comment: Still not working. Right now I have called time totalsteps. Each simulation lasts 5200 totalsteps. Also R0 is set to 0.03 and T=0.7. If ratio is less than T then R0 should be set to 0 for 520 totalsteps then set back to 0.03 after the 520 totalsteps is completed. Does the code above do that? I now get an error message that this isn't something you can use "set" on.

Comment: Perhaps I can clarify better. I have a model where each simulation has 5200 total ticks. I call them totalsteps.

I have a parameter called R0 which is set to 0.03. I have another parameter T. 

I would like to program the following:

If ratio < T then set R0 to 0.00 for 520 ticks, then increase R0 by 0.0025 every 12 ticks until R0=0.06.


Here is a hypothetical:

Comment: From totalstep 0 to 1050 ratio > T. At totalstep 1051 ratio < T, so R0 decreases from 0.03 to 0. At total step 1571 R0 increases to 0.0025. Then at totalstep 1583 R0 increases to 0.0050, etc until R0=0.06.

Comment: Is it possible to compensate to help get the right answer?

Comment: King-Ink. Will do. Thank you

Comment: Send me a message and I will redact my email

Comment: thank you, sorry with the holidays did not get to access internet. Email is sent.